# how to compress lines of code with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following lines of code that I am using.  But it just seems redunent and I was curious if there is an optimized alternative to the following...

```
if(mkey[65]){ //this is left! (a)
    var nextpos = $("#item").x()-player.speed;
    if(nextpos > 0){
        $("#item").x(nextpos);
    }
}
if(mkey[68]){ //this is right! (d)
    var nextpos = $("#item").x()+player.speed;
    if(nextpos < pg.width - 100){
        $("#item").x(nextpos);
    }
}
if(mkey[87]){ //this is up! (w)
    var nextpos = $("#item").y()-player.speed;
    if(nextpos > 0){
        $("#item").y(nextpos);
    }
}
if(mkey[83]){ //this is down! (s)
    var nextpos = $("#item").y()+player.speed;
    if(nextpos < pg.height - 30){
        $("#item").y(nextpos);
    }
}
```

I thought about using the jquery each method, but it only took me so far, because I don't know if you can store custom JavaScript functions into data objects...

Thanks for any advice!

**This is what I have tried...(no luck)**

```
$.each([
    {keypress: mkey[65], item:$("#item").x()-player.speed},
    {keypress: mkey[68], item:$("#item").x()+player.speed},
    {keypress: mkey[87], item:$("#item").y()-player.speed},
    {keypress: mkey[83], item:$("#item").y()+player.speed}
], function(i, obj) {

     if (obj.keypress) {
  if(obj.item > 0) { $("#item").x(obj.item);}
  }

});
```

Comment: *[what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)*

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, a function is an object, so that's not an issue. The issue is whether you'd save any lines of code by using one, and even if you did, whether it was maintainable. Here's a possible solution:

```
$.each([
    { which: 65, fn: $('#item').x, plus: -player.speed, comparison: 'gt', what: 0 },
    { which: 68, fn: $('#item').x, plus: player.speed, comparison: 'lt', what: pg.width - 30),
    { which: 87, fn: $('#item').y, plus: -player.speed, comparison: 'gt', what: 0 },
    { which: 83, fn: $('#item').y, plus: player.speed, comparison: 'lt', what: pg.height - 30)
], function () {
    var o = this,
        w = mkey[o.which],
        nextpos = o.fn() + o.plus;
    if ((o.comparison === 'gt' && nextpos > o.what) || 
        (o.comparison === 'lt' && nextpos < o.what)) {
        o.fn(nextpos);
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this or anything (provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/) with your code and I can), but hopefully you can see where I'm going with it. Again, not sure if this actually helps, as this code is much less readable than the original. With minification, the original code will run much faster that this code. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you and I really appreciate you taking out time to help me with this. Still investigating...

Answer (score 1):

use a switch statement on keycode.

There is also the which, but im not a fan of it:
http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Switch statement

```
switch($keycode){

case 43:
// Your code or function_name();
break;

case 99:
// Your code or function_name();
break;
}
```

Comment: how would you set up a switch case for multiple functions?